# The server's host key is not cached in the registry

Tags: windows, ssh, cache, transfer, psftp

There is a scheduled job to send files via psftp command (psftp -bc -v -P 22 -l username -pw password        -b upload220506.ftp ftpsitename) in windows server. It is already cached by running exe file manually from command prompt as administrator. The first file was transferred successfully through the job and the second file was failed and seeing the following message in the log. How shall I avoid this issue when sending multiple files?

*Using Diffie-Hellman with standard group "group14"
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)*

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
C:\putty\psftp.exe -i C:\connections\FTP\remote-server.ppk myuser@remote-server -batch -bc -be -b C:\putty\upload.txt -hostkey 39:e4:84:b2:6f:bc:87:04:1f:21:bf:32:83:79:0b:cf
```

https://bytefreaks.net/windows/psftp-exe-the-servers-host-key-is-not-cached-in-the-registry-you-have-no-guarantee-that-the-server-is-the-computer-you-think-it-is